# Canon MP280 scanner not working

Tags: canon, scanner

I have a Canon mp280 all-in-one. I have tried many things to get the scanner to work but everything failed. When I run `sane - find - scanner` ubuntu replies:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x1746 [MP280 series]) at libusb:001:004
found USB scanner (vendor=0x0846, product=0x9018) at libusb:001:003
```

I have the following packages intalled:

```
Canon Printer Driver Common Modules-  cndrvcups-common 2.50-1-2~precise1 
IJ Printer Driver for Linux.-         cnijfilter-common 3.90-63~precise1
IJ Printer Driver for Linux.          cnijfilter-mp280series 3.90-63~precise1
ScanGear MP for Linux.                scangearmp-common 2.10-33~precise1
ScanGear MP for Linux.                scangearmp-mp280series 2.10-33~precise1
```

The printer works since the first day I installed ubuntu but the scanner never.

I have tried the following softwares:

- Xsane
- Simple Scan
- Scanlite

I have installed the PPA's as described buy Ubuntu ask pages in:

http://www.launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk

I added:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
```

plus:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Just before I send this question I run `scangearamp`
from terminal and it FINALLY WORKED. but only typing the above command in the
terminal.

Is there something I can do to improve that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [official drivers from Canon](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MP_series/PIXMA_MP280.aspx?type=download&page=1)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the drivers from Canon, the ScanGear application is there too.

Run `scangearmp`. That command can be added into a `.desktop` file, like [so](https://askubuntu.com/a/725412/47206).

Or run from Gimp: File-Create-SangearMP.

ScanGear can save as pdf

[image]